# Why underline is usually used in the sql table names rather than camel case

Tags: sql, case-sensitive, case-insensitive

In all the applications/examples I have already seen(eg. wordpress). The column table names use underline rather than camel case. I'd like to know if there are some technical incompatibility problems or it's a convention? Is it dependent of the system platform(Linux/Windows) or the sql dialect(Mysql, postgreSQL, DB2, Oracle, ...). For example in the following table I have used camel case and I haven't already had any problems/warnings about it! If I should/must refactor my table, why should/must I do it?

Is SQL case insensitive about the table/column names? What about the dialects?

```
CREATE TABLE `testuser` (
  `id` bigint(20) NOT NULL,
  `user_type` varchar(8) NOT NULL,
  `username` varchar(30) DEFAULT NULL,
  `password` varchar(128) DEFAULT NULL,
  `regDate` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `username` (`username`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

Comment: Who is "everyone"? I don't use underscores.

Comment: We use underscores, but with TBL_ALL_CAPS!  Can't be helped I guess ;)

Comment: You must not do anything. It's mostly personal preference, or corporate standards that dictate how to name your tables/columns. And yeah, camelCase could make a difference if your database is Case Sensitive. That's at least the case for MS SQL Server.

Comment: Whether SQL is case sensitive depends on the collation that is being used. And the default collation for different database systems varies (some have *a* default, others allow you to choose a default during installation). So, it depends.

Comment: ok! I change everyone to "usualy"! but I gave an example - wordpress - another example can be mediawiki see this for example: http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual:Category_table At least according to what I have seen in different Open source projects. This has been a recurrent pattern however I have already seen only the opensource projects, because I have never worked in a company that makes closed source projects.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever: you should rephrase that to "*Whether **MySQL** is case sensitive ...*" as other DBMS behave differently and usually don't depend their syntax behaviour on configuration settings and/or the operating system (yes, in MySQL this also depends on the operating system you use, or more precise: which filesystem).

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name if it is difficult or impossible to ask this question about different DBMS, let's change it to only mysql/postgreSql/mssql/oracle Or even one of them. However I prefer to get the answer at least for these databases to learn a safe way and apply it when I should decide for the naming conventions of my projects.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name - I was answering generally. Hence my second sentence about "database systems". E.g. SQL Server can be either also.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever: I understand. But if I'm not mistaken no other DBMS (other than SQL Server and MySQL) can be configured to behave differently in in different installation regarding the case-sensitivity.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

A bit of background information:

The (ANSI) SQL standard requires that non-quoted identifiers are stored in all uppercase in the system catalogs and that non-quoted identifiers are case-insensitive.

According to the standard the following non-quoted identifiers reference the same object (e.g. a table): `FOOBAR`, `foobar`, `FooBar` (and all would have been stored as `FOOBAR` in the system catalogs).

The following **quoted** identifiers reference 3 different objects: `"FOOBAR"`, `"foobar"`, `"FooBar"`.

Nearly all DBMS comply at least with the requirement that non-quoted identifiers are case **insensitive**. Except for MySQL and SQL Server as far as I know - both can be configured to be case-sensitive even for non-quoted identifiers. I'm not sure what the default behaviour of SQL Server is though (as Damien pointed out in his comment, this depends on the collation being used for SQL Server).

MySQL is even more confusing as its behaviour depends on the combination of several configuration settings, the storage engine and the filesystem. All other DBMS I know are consistent regarding their behaviour across all platforms and installations.

PostgreSQL complies with the case-sensitivity but it folds everything to lowercase.

So given these rules, I *think* that the "traditional" naming convention using underscores stems from the fact that object names are stored in uppercase. The only way to get "readable" names is to separate important parts of the name with underscores.

SQL Server is even more non-standard as it is case-preserving (similar to the way NTFS under Windows works) so it does not fold the names to anything. So it does not change the case of the name when it's stored in the system catalog (but it is by default case insensitive). For that reason you will find people working in a Microsoft environment using CamelCase more often then e.g. in an Oracle environment.